# Using Ajax Js for searching inside of div - too much text on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, search

we are running e-shop on Prestashop and we need to create Ajax search to find battery and adapter compatibilities on page.

I have made this code: `https://jsfiddle.net/fgfjo2n9/`

I have 2 problems.

• 1st
I need output to display only heading with compatibilities, not all headings.
Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmmtu.jpg

•2nd
We have alot of compatibilities, so page is very slow when you try to search. Is there any way without database, to increase speed while searching?

Demo of slow load: `www.powerparts.cz/adaptery-k-notebookum/9-nabijecka-na-notebook-asus-lenovo-msi-toshiba-19v-342a-55x25#idTab_dm_newtab`

Thanks alot for any help or tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display only the heading with compatibilities you can alter your `$(".komp").each` function like so

```
$(".komp").each(function(){
    // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        //added
        if($(this).siblings(':hidden')) {
            $(this).parent().prev().fadeOut();
        }

    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
    } else {
        $(this).parent().prev().fadeIn(); //added
        $(this).show();
        count++;
    }
});
```

**Explanation**: Check if all the siblings/items are hidden (`$(this).siblings(':hidden')`) and if so, `fadeOut` the parents' previous element(heading) else if any one of the siblings/items matches the search then show(`fadeIn`) the heading.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fgfjo2n9/1/)

Secondly, to **improve the performance of your search**, you could implement techniques like **Lazy Loading** & moving few scripts to the bottom of the body etc. There is much more to it and hence have provided you with links to go through.

- https://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/
- http://desalasworks.com/article/javascript-performance-techniques/